# Socket IO client connection status

Tags: react-native, socket.io

I am developing a chat app using React Native with Socket IO. When the apps goes to background, socket IO is disconnected at server side after approximately 15 seconds. When the apps comes to foreground again, I want to check see if socket io client is connected or not.

Looking through the documents I know there is a function called socket.connected like below:

```
socket.on('connect', () => {
  console.log(socket.connected); // true
});
```

and

```
socket.on('disconnect', () => {
  console.log(socket.disconnected); // true
});
```

But both these functions will not be called until socket is reconnected. After socket is reconnected, **socket.connected** returns true and **socket.disconnected** returns false. I want to check the connection status before socket tries to reconnect. How can I do that?

Comment: If the API doesn't give you such as method like `checkState` Can you not check if the App is in the background/foreground? Store the connection state in your App state, for example when disconnect is fired, update your app state to reflect this and vice versa? When you open your app up, you check the connection state via the App state - while the connection is re-established.

Comment: I tried to do that, but the socket.disconnect function does not fire at my client side even though it fired at server side. It only fires after socket reconnected..

Comment: Would you be able to post some code? Have you checked your device log to see if the event is cancelled somewhere, perhaps the RN bridge is destroyed? You may have to go down the route of checking if the app is in the foreground/background - but that seems crazy!